# Set launchurl for production environment in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi

I have implemented Swagger in my Web API (ASP.NET Core 3.1) and my launch url is `/swagger`. I have edited my `launchSettings.json` in order of this, and it works good in my development machine, but not after publishing in production server.

I have read that `launchSettings.json` is only used on the local development machine, and if I want to use certain of these settings in the production machine I need to store such settings in the `appsettings.json` file.

But I couldn't find how to set this file. Some help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can review this [ASP.NET Core Environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Add production profile to your launchsettings.json file.

Comment: Thank you for reply, but as far as I know `launchsettings.json` is only usted by Visual Studio in the developement machine. You can set profiles in orden to test your app, but this file will not be implemented in the production machine.

Comment: Okay, Add new file named appsettings.Development.json to project and configure for your visual studio running. appSettings.json file is default production file. You can configure appSettings.json for production.

Answer (score 1):

In the launchSettings.json the launch URL is the page that is opened when the application starts. Is this the setting you are looking for? (In my opinion in a production environment this is not a relevant setting.)

If I am correct in the production environment the /swagger URL doesn't load when you open it in a browser. The reason for this could be an "if (env.IsDevelopment) {...}" or something similar in the Startup class which conditionally adds the swagger middleware.

Comment: yes, but settings in launchSettings.json applies only in Visual Studio, and they have no effects after publishing. Since Swagger builts an user interface and the documentation for the API, I see very useful it loads on start. It is also true that I always can create a redirect in web.config.

Comment: I don't really understand what you really want. launchUrl is mainly for dev environment. If you run an app in prod environment, it wouldn't be useful that it would start a browser on the prod server.

If you want to redirect every request that is not an api route to the swagger UI than that's a completely other question.

Also launcSettings can be used with the dotnet CLI tool, not only with VS:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed **launchSettings.json** environments are only used within the local development machine.

Here you have a simple way to achieve it in the production server with endpoint redirection:

**Startup.cs**

```
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapGet("/", context => {
        context.Response.Redirect("swagger");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The settings that are present within this file are going to be used when we run the .NET core application either from Visual Studio or by using .NET Core CLI.

The most important point that you need to keep in mind is this **launchSettings.json** file is only used within the **local development machine**. That means this file is not required when we publishing our asp.net core application to the production server.

If you have certain settings and you want your application to use such settings when you publish and deploy your asp.net core application to the production server, then you need to store such settings in the **appsettings.json** file. Generally, in the ASP.NET Core application, the configuration settings are going to be stored in the **appsettings.json** file.

You can read this nice article about this topic : [Article](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/asp-net-core-launchsettings-json-file/)

Comment: Thank you, but that point is clear, and I started the topic refering to it. The real question is: how can I set the default route in a .net mvc web api project in production enviroment? Is appSettings.json the correct place to set it up? how?

Comment: Ok. You can set launch url in program.cs. [Check this blog](https://www.google.com/amp/s/andrewlock.net/5-ways-to-set-the-urls-for-an-aspnetcore-app/amp/)